# How to stop the event bubble in easljs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I have a mousedown event listener on stage and a mousedown event listener on a shape.when I click on the shape, the mousedown event listener on stage will also fire? How to solve this?

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("test");
stage.addEventListener('stagemousedown',mouseDown);
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginStroke("#000").setStrokeStyle(8,"round").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
shape.addEventListener('mousedown',smouseDown);
stage.addChild(shape);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stagemousedown event is a special event to always capture stage mouse interaction, regardless of what is clicked. If you would like to ONLY receive that event when a child on the stage is not clicked there are other approaches.

One suggestion would be to add a stage-level child that is the size of the stage, and listen for mouse events on it. You can then check the target to see what was clicked (or not clicked)

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

var bg = new createjs.Shape();
bg.graphics.f("#ddd").dr(0,0,550,400);

var shape = new createjs.Shape().set({x:200,y:200});
shape.graphics.f("#f00").dc(0,0,100);

stage.addChild(bg, shape);
stage.update();

stage.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    if (event.target == bg) {
        console.log("Missed Content");
    } else {
        console.log("Hit Content");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the ways to remove the shape object in the stage.

```
stage.removeChild(shape);
```

you can put that in a function and just call it when you want to remove the object.

please let me know if that is what you need.

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe a better way, but you could check if there is no object under the mouse when you catch the "stagemousedown" event :

```
function mouseDown(event) {
    if (stage.getObjectUnderPoint(event.stageX,event.stageY) == null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This idea seems good.But mousedown on a hitArea also get "stage.getObjectUnderPoint(e.stageX,e.stageY) == null".

Comment: I tried here : http://jsfiddle.net/f6TzD/7/. I set a hitArea bigger than my object catching the mouse event. And it seems that the object is still recognized wherever I click on the hitArea.

Comment: I found the problem.When you use the latest createjs or easeljs it won't work correctly.But when you use the createjs in jsfiddle , it works well.

Comment: Then I may have a tricky solution. To all the objects which are not added to the stage you could add the "mouseover" and "mouseout" event listeners where you set a boolean to true/false. Then the condition in your mouseDown function would be "stage.getObjectUnderPoint(e.stageX,e.stageY) == null && !yourBool"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `stage.mouseEnabled = false`:

> Indicates whether to include this object when running mouse
>   interactions. Setting this to false for children of a Container will
>   cause events on the Container to not fire when that child is clicked.
>   Setting this property to false does not prevent the
>   getObjectsUnderPoint method from returning the child.

However, from the [docs](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#property_mouseChildren):

> Note: In EaselJS 0.7.0, the mouseEnabled property will not work
>   properly with nested Containers. Please check out the latest NEXT
>   version in GitHub for an updated version with this issue resolved. The
>   fix will be provided in the next release of EaselJS.